# ArcGIS Python: Using Calendars in the Graphical Interface Forms

Tags: python, forms, calendar, arcgis, arcpy

I am a GIS Specialist using Python within ArcGIS10. I am creating a script and importing it into the the ArcGIS default graphical interface form. In the default forms, I can set certain parameters made of different data types. One of the parameters I would like to set is to have a field where the user opens a calendar and selects a date to be passed into the script. Because I am working within ArcGIS, I am not sure if I can add this field or not. If anyone needs more clarification as to what I want to do, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the script in an ArcGIS 10 toolbox, a calendar popup is not possible.  Even worse, it does not look like the Date data type provides any validation from the toolbox.  This means that you will need to either validate that an actual date has been entered in your code or you can modify the validation code in the script properties to do this.  I would do it in both.

Comment: Does anyone have any update on this for 10.1 - or know if it is going to be a future consideration at a new release?